# MFMailComposeViewController ModalView crashes the iOS5 application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, crash, modalviewcontroller

I have an iOS TabBar Application with tabbarcontroller and navigationcontroller.
In my detail view wich is pushed from my first tab tableviewcontroller i have sharing navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem with email sharing.

I have the following code for this:

```
    - (void)share
{   
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Email",nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

      if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [picker setMailComposeDelegate:self];
            [picker setSubject:@"New theme"];
            NSString *emailBody = @"Hi there";
            [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
            [self resignFirstResponder];
            picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
            [picker release];

        }
        else{
        }
}
}
```

The app shows me the composing view but when i'm trying to do something with this view (e.g. to pick up the address or to spell something) - app crashes with SIGTRAP.

The app crashes only in iOS5, iOS5.1. In iOS4.2.1 everything works perfect.

What's the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: If you set an exception breakpoint or otherwise trap the exception, what is the message and the stack trace?

Comment: what i can see in my crittercism dashboard: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YTec1-gnrIhSUkvt66RcIouwtjgu6HgF2CTQcQ21pCw/edit  and here's what i see in xcode in main thread: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AKLqTYYoTa8TcfRJ6-BEEHnafzT-w6NaV8frvPdoOB8/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help and your time.
It was absolutely insane bug. Project has a cyrillic name. I just renamed it to latin name and now everything works fine. My fault :( Thanks [Evgeniy Shurakov](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/evgeniyshurakov) for the help.

Comment: dude, can you please explain in brief about this problem. I'm also facing same issue but enable to resolve it.im not getting cyrillic and latin difference.

Comment: that's strange. My problem was - cyrillic name. That's why my app crashed. I renamed the project everywhere (look carefully through all project files and replace cyrillic name with latin).

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs, I'd suggest calling `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` class method before creating `MFMailComposeViewController`. I also generally don't have that `[self resignFirstResponder]` line. I gather you're crashing before your `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error` method is invoked?

Comment: I'm calling canSendMail before creating the controller (there was a mistake in code above). So here's the code: `if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
                MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; ` And i've tried it without `resignFirstResponder` - the same error. You're right, i'm crashing before `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error` method is invoked.

Comment: Curious. And we're sure that this delegate object still exists at the time that the `CFMailComposeViewController` is presented to the user, too? I could imagine some weird crash if the object that you've defined as the `CFMailComposeViewController`'s delegate has been released (which is easy to do because even though you're presenting a modal view, your code continues to execute). Maybe NSLog in your -(void)dealloc or something like that just to make sure.

Comment: You're right, `(void)dealloc` method of the delegate (`self`) is called after my detail view (which is the `CFMailComposeViewController`'s delegate) is pushed. Tried it on iOS4 - `(void)dealloc` is called, but everything works fine.

Comment: Don't quite know why it worked on iOS4 as `dealloc`ing an active delegate should be problematic. But at least a solution for your iOS5 problem is in sight!

Comment: I've tried another controllers (tabBarController and NavigationController) as the delegate. Nothing worked. Actually, the iOS5.1 simulator works fine too. :(

Comment: I would have thought that whatever is the main view controller that the user returns to might be a logical candidate. Whatever it is, it must (a) conform to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`; (b) have a `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` method; and (c) exist during the entire life of the `MFMailComposeViewController`. It's just like your action sheet: You never want to create an action sheet and get rid of the delegate object before the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` has a chance to be called. Same thing with the MessageUI framework.

Comment: Ok. So for now i have the DetailViewController from which i'm presenting the modal view. And it (a)is conform to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`; (b) has a `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` method; and (c) exists during the entire life of the `MFMailComposeViewController` (no dealloc called before or while modalview is presented). But still i have this error on iOS5 and correct work on iOS4.

Comment: I have something extremely weird now. Everything works fine on iOS5 when i'm turning off the WiFi. ?!?!

Comment: I have no idea why that would be. That's very curious. If you were using Reachability, I'd wonder if you were doing something funky there. But many of us are using `MFMailComposeViewController` without this sort of issue. Sorry I can't be more helpful.